# TinyMCE3/4 stripping html tags

Tags: magento2

I noticed that tinyMCE often strips 'wrong' html tags. Like divs inside a tags and sometimes spans. I found out that you can add some configuration to disable this behaviour but i'm not sure how to implement it. After some playing around i came to this script but it doesn't actually prevent the stripping and i'm not sure why. I'm using M2.3.4 with TinyMCE 4 but it would be nice if the script would work for tinyMCE 3 to to use it for multiple shops.

**BB\TinyMCEStripping\Plugin\WysiwygConfig.php**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace BB\TinyMCEStripping\Plugin;

class WysiwygConfig
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Ui\Component\Wysiwyg\ConfigInterface $configInterface
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $result
     * @return \Magento\Framework\DataObject
     */
    public function afterGetConfig(
        \Magento\Ui\Component\Wysiwyg\ConfigInterface $configInterface,
        \Magento\Framework\DataObject $result
    )
    {
        $settings = $result->getData('settings');
        $settings['valid_children'] = '+a[div]';

        $settings['trim_span_elements'] = false;
        $settings['verify_html'] = false;
        $settings['cleanup'] = false;
        $settings['convert_urls'] = false;

        $result->setData('settings', $settings);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

**BB\TinyMCEStripping\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Ui\Component\Wysiwyg\ConfigInterface">
        <plugin name="plugin_wysiwyg_config"
                type="BigBridge\TinyMCEStripping\Plugin\WysiwygConfig"
                sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>

</config>
```

**BB\TinyMCEStripping\etc\module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="BB_TinyMCEStripping" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

**BB\TinyMCEStripping\registration.php**

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(
    ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'BB_TinyMCEStripping',
    __DIR__
);
```

Anyone have an idea how to finish this script?